a rigorous relation between distrubution function and density function in higher dimensions
Let $X$ be a random variable taking values from $\mathbb{R}^d$ whose distribution is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure. Let $F_X, f_X$ be the distribution and density functions of $X$, from their definitions, we know
$$F_X(x) = p(X_1 \leq x_1, \cdots, X_d \leq x_d) = \int_{(-\infty,x_1]\times\cdots\times(-\infty,x_d]}f_Xd\lambda$$
for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure.
When $d = 1$, we can conclude from the Lebesgue differentiation theorem that $F_X$ is differentiable with $F_X' = f_X$ almost everywhere.
I wonder if similar results can be proved for the multivariate case. Will $F_X$ still be differentiable when $d > 1$? I have seen some texts claiming without justification that
$$\frac{\partial^dF_X}{\partial x_1\cdots\partial x_d} = f_X.$$
However, even if $F_X$ is differentiable in the sense that it admits a total derivative, the LHS above is not even guaranteed to exist...... So when will the relation hold?

Use iterated integrals and you wiil see how that works.
